# How to make unanswered questions more enticing?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get attention for your old, unanswered questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-to-get-attention-for-your-old-unanswered-questions)

I have a question that I havn't gotten any feed back on. I was wondering if there was a way to make these questions more enticing so the experts might want to take a look? My question is [sql server 2008 dynamic pivot based on ordinal value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022742/sql-server-2008-dynamic-pivot-based-on-ordinal). I would gladly provide more information if needed but have gotten little feed back. Is a feature of this type possible or is it just kind of the luck of the draw? Thanks.

Comment: You've pretty much just summed up what [the bounty system](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/131713) is for.

Comment: Oh I see. Ok, I'll just wait till I get the points to do that. Thanks for the help. I was kinda getting at, maybe the wording or tag suggestions, etc. because I think it will be a while till I'm capable of setting a bounty. hehe! I'm a new user.

Comment: You may also be interested in [How to get attention for your old, unanswered questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-to-get-attention-for-your-old-unanswered-questions).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'll try and use some of those tactics. Thanks again.

Comment: @Popular Demand, wow I think just posting this question got people to look at my question because now I'm getting feedback. You guys are quick! Thanks.